# Could not locate appropriate constructor on class

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to map my native SQL result to my POJO, but it's returning an error. 
Here is the full stack trace:

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM members_tb where memberName like ?
2019-12-19 07:40:20.688 TRACE 32472 --- [nio-8084-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [%Frank%]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : com.app.ecclesiamainframe.entity.Members
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.resolveConstructor(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:2338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2123)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1134)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at com.app.ecclesiamainframe.service.impl.MembersServiceImpl.findByMembername(MembersServiceImpl.java:63)
    at com.app.ecclesiamainframe.service.impl.MembersServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b6791a90.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.app.ecclesiamainframe.service.impl.MembersServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81c0914a.findByMembername(<generated>)
    at com.app.ecclesiamainframe.controller.MembersController.getMember(MembersController.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-12-19 07:40:21.744  INFO 32472 --- [nio-8084-exec-2] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    1250700 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
2019-12-19 08:39:48.231  WARN 32472 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=45s935ms542µs800ns).
2019-12-19 08:46:56.149  WARN 32472 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=3m17s562ms942µs).
2019-12-19 08:46:57.264  WARN 32472 --- [l-2 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-2 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=3m17s563ms485µs800ns).
```

Here is my Membermapping.xml:

```xml
<sql-result-set-mapping name="MemberMappingXml">
    <constructor-result target-class="com.app.ecclesiamainframe.entity.Members">
      <column name="memberId" />
      <column name="dcaRegno" />
      <column name="address" />
      <column name="age" />
      <column name="areaId" />
      <column name="birthday" />
      <column name="cellId" />
      <column name="dca" />
      <column name="department" />
      <column name="editor" />
      <column name="firstTime" />
      <column name="gender" />
      <column name="maritalStatus" />
      <column name="memberEmail" />
      <column name="memberHomePhoneNum" />
      <column name="memberMobileNum" />
      <column name="memberName" />
      <column name="note" />
      <column name="secondTime" />      
    </constructor-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

Here is my Entity Class:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.app.ecclesiamainframe.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.ConstructorResult;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType;

import lombok.Data;

/**
 * @author Harry
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="members_tb")
@Data
@TypeDef(
    name = "json", 
    typeClass = JsonStringType.class
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "MemberMapping",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = Members.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "memberId", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "dcaRegno", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "address"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "age"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "areaId", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "birthday"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "cellId", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "dca"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "department"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "editor"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "firstTime"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "gender"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "maritalStatus"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "memberEmail"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "memberHomePhoneNum", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "memberMobileNum", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "memberName"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "note"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "secondTime")

    }))
public class Members implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Members() {}


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="memberId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long memberId;

    @Column(name="dcaRegno")
    private Long dcaRegno;

    @Column(name="memberName")
    private String memberName;

    @Column(name="memberMobileNum")
    private Long memberMobileNum;

    @Column(name="memberHomePhoneNum")
    private Long memberHomePhoneNum;

    @Column(name="memberEmail")
    private String memberEmail;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="department")
    private String department;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json",name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="cellId")
    private Long cellId;

    @Column(name="areaId")
    private Long areaId;

    @Column(name="maritalStatus")
    private String maritalStatus;

    @Column(name="age")
    private String age;

    @Column(name="birthday")
    private String birthday;

    @Column(name="firstTime")
    private String firstTime;

    @Column(name="secondTime")
    private String secondTime;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json",name="dca")
    private String dca;

    @Column(name="note")
    private String note;

    @Column(name="editor")
    private String editor;

    public Members(Long memberId,String memberName) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
        this.memberName = memberName;
    }

    public Members(Long memberId,Long dcaRegno,String memberName,Long memberMobileNum,Long memberHomePhoneNum,String memberEmail,String gender,String department,
               String address,Long cellId,Long areaId,String maritalStatus,String age,String birthday,String firstTime,String secondTime,
               String dca,String note,String editor) {

    this.memberId = memberId;
    this.dcaRegno = dcaRegno;
    this.address = address;
    this.age = age;
    this.areaId = areaId;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.cellId = cellId;
    this.dca = dca;
    this.department = department;
    this.editor = editor;
    this.firstTime = firstTime;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    this.memberEmail = memberEmail;
    this.memberHomePhoneNum = memberHomePhoneNum;
    this.memberMobileNum = memberMobileNum;
    this.memberName = memberName;
    this.note = note;
    this.secondTime = secondTime;
  } 
}
```

Here is my Member Service Implementation:

```
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Members> findByMembername(String memberName) 
{
    //return membersDao.findByMemberName(memberName);
     List<Members> members = null;
    try {
         session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
         transaction = session.beginTransaction();

      // Native query selecting all columns
         Query query = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM members_tb where memberName like :memberName","MemberMapping")
                 .setParameter("memberName","%"+memberName+"%"); //named parameter binding 
                members = query.getResultList();
         transaction.commit(); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         if (session != null) {
            session.close();
         }
      }
     // HibernateUtil.shutdown();
      return members;
}
```

***Please how do i do away with the error and design an appropriate constructor ???
 Possibly if i don't have to load every column into the constructor although i want all columns mapped in the result.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a constructor for this.

Create a constructor in the class in which you have used `SqlResultsetMapping` and keep the variables in the constructor in the same sequence as you have kept them in the `SqlResultsetMapping`

Answer (score 1):

The listed columns are not in the same order as the constructor parameters.

```
Parameters                  Columns
=========================   ==================
Long   memberId             memberId
Long   dcaRegno             dcaRegno
String memberName           address
Long   memberMobileNum      age
Long   memberHomePhoneNum   areaId
String memberEmail          birthday
String gender               cellId
String department           dca
String address              department
Long   cellId               editor
Long   areaId               firstTime
String maritalStatus        gender
String age                  maritalStatus
String birthday             memberEmail
String firstTime            memberHomePhoneNum
String secondTime           memberMobileNum
String dca                  memberName
String note                 note
String editor               secondTime
```

Answer (score 0):

please create this constructor in pojo class.As i can see mismatch between constructor

Members(Long memberId,Long dcaRegno,String address,String age,Long areaId,String birthday,Long cellId,String dca,String department,String editor,String firstTime,String gender,String maritalStatus,String memberEmail,Long memberHomePhoneNum,Long memberMobileNum,String memberName,String note,String secondTime)

hope this will work for you